# Automatically georectify raw Landsat scenes

Tags: georeferencing, coordinate-system, landsat, orthorectification

I am working with 20 raw **Landsat images** downloaded from GloVis, in **WGS 84** (EPSG 32634) coordinate system. I need to geometrically correct them **to S_JTSK** (EPSG 5514). 
Usually, georectification is done manually using set of control points (same location in georeferenced map and image I want to georectify). However Landsat resolution is so poor (30x30m) that I can´t find easily these points.

In this reason I would like to know **if there is some automated approach to georectify Landsat scenes**?

maybe using scene corners as a Control points?

but how to find them in my S_JTSK map?

I can´t use ArcGIS Tool ´Georeferencing a raster automatically´ because my Landsat image has already a coordinate system.

I am working with ArcGIS, ERDAS and R.

Comment: Are your images in the correct position in WGS84? Then you might try the "Project Raster" tool.

Comment: yeah, thanks @Gabor Farkas, I´ve already found it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your data is already in UTM 34N projection, all you have to do is reproject it to your local CRS.

You can do this with gdalwarp (even in batch mode for a whole folder), or inside QGIS with `Raster -> Projections -> Warp` . ARCGIS should offer similar tools.

So no need for georeferencing manually.

Comment: As @AndreJ says you need to reproject your data. i don´t think you need to georectify your data

Comment: Hi @AndreJ, thanks for your proposition,  it works! in ArcGIS 10.1 the same tool is in Data Management -> Projection and Transformation -> Raster -> Project raster (not Warp like in QGis).  I didnt know that it is so easy to do ! :)